# Extend network with a router as AP or with dhcp disabled

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wired-networking

I have a modem/router on 1st floor from the provider and I want to extend my network on 2nd floor. I have Ethernet cable from 1st floor to 2nd floor. What is the best way to do it? I have a router Asus RT-AC68U. I think of 2 cases:

- Using RT-AC68U as an access point
- Using RT-AC68U as a "LAN-LAN router" with DHCP and NAT disabled.

What are the advantages and what are the disadvantages? Is there a better way to extend the network?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have Ethernet from first to second floor, the best way (in my opinion) to hook it is to hook it up as per case 2 above. That way, your extension is on the same network as your main network. I do this and it works exceedingly well.

1. Hook up a LAN port on the second floor router to a LAN port on your network.
2. Give the second floor router a static IP address on the main network.
3. Turn DHCP OFF on the second floor router.

You may need to restart the second floor router when you have completed the changes.

I do this and it works a treat: Computers and iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

If you want WLAN access, I would go with your first suggestion and use the RT-AC68U as an access point.

If you don't need WLAN access I would disable the routing functionality as well and just use it as a switch (or just buy a switch they are inexpensive fast and use less power then you can use the router with it's functionality s.w. else). You only need a router if you need to use different subnets otherwise it will just cost you performance and energy (a router is much less efficient then a switch).

Of course you can combine both solutions as well and use the router as a switch as well as a AP. If possible I would always prefer to use a wired network connection (better speed, reliability and additional features like wake on LAN).

Answer (score 0):

If you use access point (AP) mode, you will use up the wan port (commonly) of RT-AC68U, leaving all the lan ports free.

If you want to establish a LAN-LAN setup, then you will use a lan port of RT-AC68U, leaving you with one less lan port.

Logically both ways are same, and in AP mode, the router automatically disables DHCP and NAT.

But in my router, you cannot customize many options that need a wan connection like the wireless channel in AP mode, so if you want some feature that is disabled in AP mode, go for LAN-LAN configuration .